# Push Notification from Web based application to Android

Tags: android, mysql, web, push-notification, pull

I have developed web based application using yii2 framework and MySQL database and my plan is i want to make an android app that can receive notification from my web based application real time and can pull data from it too. but i'm not sure how can make it works and using which methods i can implement this. can you give me some advise and source to learn it?
thanks

Comment: look at GCM.  https://developers.google.com/cloud-messaging/android/start

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to follow below steps to implement push notification

1) You have to register on google developer consol
https://accounts.google.com/ServiceLogin?service=cloudconsole&osid=1&passive=true&continue=https://console.developers.google.com/dcredirect/

2)enable the GCM api from api list that available in api lists further instruction you will get on site when you create account.

3)Generate key for GCM web/ android.

4) Use this GCM key from android app and write the the GCM notification receiver 
program in android app and using notification manager show on notification bar.

5)Using server side key you can write the program to push notification from web site.

Comment: what comes first, register the GCM first or make the android apps first?

Comment: As you want you can do but practicaly without key you can not do . I mean your programs would not work without Key.

Comment: oh so i can make a key first than make an android apps?